# font looks Blurry Pycharm Mac

Tags: fonts, pycharm, settings

I am not sure what I changed by accident. But now my pycharm fonts looks blurry. 
Now it looks like this:

**blurry fonts**
[image]

Before, it looks clear like this:

**old clear font**
[image]

Does anyone have a clue on how to fix it? I tried to uninstall and reinstall, it does not help.

Answer (score 1):

There is a similar question posted on jetbrains support forum [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207330355-Fonts-are-Blurry-on-the-Ultimate-Edition-Mac).

Try:

1. Setting anti aliasing to Grayscale mode.
2. Upgrade your java version.